# Not able to run any yarn cmd even after installing it

Tags: macos, yarnpkg, macos-big-sur, lerna

I was using lerna yarn workspaces to manage the my monorepos but due to dependencies incompatible version issues i downgraded my yarn version and after that yarn cmds start failing. Then i again upgraded my yarn version to latest 1.22.10 but after that no yarn cmd is running. running any cmd gives below error attached in SS:
[image]

Can someone help me in this, i have tried multiple times reinstalling node, nvm and yarn but nothing is working for me.
I have tried downloading yarn using brew, npm globally but nothing works

Comment: @jonrsharpe, what have you edited here?

Comment: You can see the changes in https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67465827/revisions or https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67465827/timeline

Answer (score 2):

Finally, after slogging for past 2 days and searching insanely online. Able to resolve this by hit and trial.

If you have yet to install or see yarn at /.yarn/ you can install it directly following https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/ or

curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash

Then follow below steps:-

1. mkdir ~/.yarn/releases/
2. cp ~/.yarn/lib/cli.js ~/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.19.0.cjs
3. yarn -v

voila, it works, Never been so happy before